# Simulando hora, fecha y alarma, escogida por el usuario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Muy buenas noches, estoy trabajando en este formulario, el cual estoy simulando el cambio de hora, fecha y alarma, ya que con javascript hasta donde se no se puede modificar la hora y fecha, por eso estoy intentando hacerlo de esta manera,el cual el usuario selecciona la hora, la alarma y fecha, la cual se guarda en una variable y se imprime.
creo que se puede simplificar mas el codigo, solo que no tengo tanta experiencia.
la alarma no he podido adaptarla a la hora seleccionada, me podrían ayudar a correjirme los errores que tengo en el código lo dejo aquí

[jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/danHD/smfpnq1j/9/)

Comment: Hola, tendrás que explicar mejor qué es lo que quieres y cuáles son los errores que no puedes solucionar. Como comprenderás no podemos arreglar cosas sin saber cuál es el objetivo final.

Comment: me disculpo por no saberme expresar bien, en jsfiddle no se por que no me funciona el contador el cual aumenta los segundos.
en la primera  opción el usuario aumenta la hora y minutos, la cual lo puedo hacer, solo guardar esa información es lo que me falta.
en la segunda opción el usuario configura la alarma para que funcione, me gustaría sincronizar la alarma con la hora que el usuario seleccione, esto no lo he podido hacer ya que la alarma esta separada. esta parte me gustaría que me ayudaran, sincronizar la alarma con la hora seleccionada.

Comment: en la opción tres me gustaría guardar la fecha configurada por el usuario.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código en la pregunta? Con Cntrl+M podrás hacerlo como en jsfiddle.

Comment: lo  he trabajado mejor aquí en :
https://codepen.io/DanielHB/pen/WNNaBRY
ya que aquí me funciona y se puede apreciar mejor, me encantaría que lo miraras y me comentaras de como puedo hacer la alarma.